# java.sql.SQLException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver'

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

We have deployed our application on tomcat server.
Java version - 1.8
Sometime our application is impacted with the error :

**SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.createMBeans Exception processing Global JNDI Resources
javax.naming.NamingException: Unexpected exception resolving reference [Root exception is java.sql.SQLException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver']**

But whenever we restart the server, it will resolved.

We get this issue once in two days.

Any help in this is appreciated .

Comment: Please add the complete exception stack trace

Comment: Unfortunately we only have this log from admin team. :(

Comment: Make sure the Oracle JDBC driver is in the class path and accessible.